# Will I still be able to call Roman to have a taxi pick me up after I finish the game with the 'Revenge' ending?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Will I still be able to call Roman to have a taxi pick me up if I choose the ['Revenge' ending](http://gta.wikia.com/Endings_in_GTA_IV)?

> In the 'Deal' ending, Roman will die. While in the 'Revenge' ending,
>  Roman will *not* die.

More info on the two GTA IV endings here: http://gta.wikia.com/Endings_in_GTA_IV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if Roman lives, you can continue using his taxi service, as long as you have 75% approval from him.